# Specifying Fonts sizes by numeric values instead of standard commands

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I need to use a custom font called Calibri in order to mimic some word form. In that word form the font size changes repeatedly.
I know of two ways to change the font size. Either at the beginning of the document.

Like this:
`\documentclass[9,5pt]{article}`

Or using the commands

`\tiny`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\huge`, etc.

Now, I can see from the word document that the title is in fontsize 18.
I would just like to specify in my latex document the fontsize using numbers, as
`\huge` etc. just don't exactly match the font size used by word.
Similarly, to the sections and subsection headings.

Comment: `\documentclass[9,5pt]{article}` will just give an unknown option warning and be the same as `\documentclass{article}`  you can  use `\fontsize{2cm}{2.5cm}\selectfont` to get a 2cm font on a 2.5cm baseline

Answer (score 3):

A Microsoft Word point is a TeX big point so you want 18bp Calibri:

With lualatex or xelatex :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}

This is 10pt 

\fontsize{18bp}{20bp}\selectfont This is 18bp (18 pt in Word/PDF/PostScript/CSS/anything-digital-that-isnt-tex)


\fontsize{3cm}{4cm}\selectfont This is quite large

\end{document}
```